# Laravel Generate Basic Auth

Tags: laravel

I am using Basic Auth ( Auth::onceBasic() ) in Laravel.

How can I generate the Token shown after 'BASIC' which is sent in the header which is automatically generated by PostMan.

I believe I need to send that token back to the user so he can login next time with that token in the header?

I wonder how can I return it back to the user from the code? In the screenshot below PostMan generates it by itself. I hope I have understood basic auth correctly. I know how to do it using Passport.

[image]

Comment: they just need credentials, the browser will base64 encode them and send them in that format  ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#Basic_authentication_scheme ... if you are not building the request yourself the browser should be prompting for credentials

Comment: @lagbox I can login just using that Basic Token only. Tried from Insomnia as well. I believe that is the purpose of that token? If not how do I send the credentials in the header?

Comment: that string is the credentials base64 encoded ... if this authentication is being used on the website and the user is using a browser, they will get prompted for their credentials, if you are using something else to make requests you will need to base64 encode the credentials to make that string

Comment: @lagbox  if you answer below I can mark your answer as the correct one. Do add to your answer : base64_encode("email@password");